# Add "Save" and "Cancel" Button in my list form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have done some changes(cascading) in my list form due to which my save and cancel buttons are removed from my form . Now I want to get them back.

Comment: Have the buttons been actually removed from the aspx page or are they just not visible?

Answer (score 2):

If you are working default list forms and you are victim of some unwanted changes and you want to revert the form to original then you can do this by following some of simple steps.

**Solution-1:**

- Open any existing form that is perfectly working from other list.
- Remove `ListFormWebpart` from broken page  "`<WebPartPages:ListFormWebPart ... to</WebPartPages:ListFormWebPart>`"
- Copy ListFormWebPart from unbroken list page open in previous and paste it into the broken form
- Paste the **List GUID** in <**ListName ... between the { and }**.
- Generate a form GUID from Visual Studio or click [here](http://www.somacon.com/p113.php) to generate new GUID and paste it into the **__WebPartID="{[Form GUID]}" > and the g_[Form GUID]**
- Save the page and refresh the list in your browser. The page should now be reverted to original

You can find detail information from [here](http://bborole.blogspot.in/2010/08/recover-broken-sharepoint-list-forms.html).

**Solution-2:**

- Navigate to the list in SP Designer.
- In the "Forms" Group click on "New" on the right of the groups title menu
- Give it a name and select the type of form you want to re-create. (New, Edit or Display)
- Check the "Set as default form for the selected type" box
- Press OK.

This solution I checked at my end. It worked.